# Get string plus a certain amount of characters after from text

Tags: c#

I couldn't seem to find an answer to my question after looking around for a bit.

I have a thing of text: "this is some text level 190 this is some more text sells for 1999"

I am needing to get the 190 value. I would just extract all numbers but most texts have more than just one set of numbers.

I've tried to substring the "level 190" but I end up getting left with characters after. How would I get rid of all text after "level 190" and pull only that specific text?

Code example:

```
string CIT = "ID 12321 ITEM name is ITEM level 100 cost some gold around 129"
string a = "level";

var index = CurrentItem.ToLower().IndexOf(a);
var final = index + 9; // Index of "level" is 28, add 4 for space and 3 numbers (level length + 4 = 9)
string CurrentItemSub = CurrentItem.Substring(index, final); // Sub it

Messagebox.Show(CurrentItemSub);
```

Comment: `$@"(?<={a}\s)\d+"`

Comment: Do you want just the number or the text 'level ' included in what you return? Seems like you really want the number after the word only

Comment: Aside: don't use `ToLower` (or `ToUpper`) when doing string comparisons/searching. Other than allocating new strings, there are gotchas that don't work for all languages (see "Turkish i" and some Hungarian chars) If you want to ignore case, use overloads that accept a `StringComparison` or `StringComparer` and use one of the `IgnoreCase` variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different ways of getting the value of "level"--assuming that the word "level" precedes the desired value.

Given the following user input: `ID 12321 has level 100 and the cost is around 129.`

**Option 1** (using Regex)

Add using statement:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

**Create a Match**

**Note**:

- `^` indicates the match must start at the beginning of the string; in multiline mode, it must start at the beginning of the line.
- `$` indicates the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the string; in multiline mode, it must occur before the end of the line or before \n at the end of the line.
- `.` Matches any single character except \n. To match a literal period character (. or \u002E), you must precede it with the escape character (\.).
- `*` matches previous element 0 or more times
- `+` matches previous element 1 or more times
- `?` matches the previous element 0 or 1 time
- `*?` matches the previous element 0 or more times, but as few times as possible
- `+?` matches the previous element one or more times, but as few times as possible

We can use the following pattern which uses a named group:

`^.+level\\s+(?<level>\\d+).+$`

**Note**: There may be other patterns that one can write that will also result in the desired data.

`^` indicates to start at the beginning of the string (or line)
`.+` indicates that any character, except \n, should be matches 1 or more times

`level` matches the word "level"

`\\s+` matches 1 or more spaces

The format for a named group is `(?<nameOfGroup>patternToMatch)`. So `(?<level>\\d+)` indicates to match 1 or more digits and place it in a group named "level".

`.+` indicates that any character, except \n, should be matches 1 or more times

`$` indicates the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the string; in multiline mode, it must occur before the end of the line or before \n at the end of the line.

See [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

```
Match match = Regex.Match(userInput, "^.+level\\s+(?<level>\\d+).+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Check if there are any matches and do something with the result:

```
if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        Group group = match.Groups[i];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("group [" + i + "]:  Name: '" + group.Name + "' Value: " + group.Value);
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Level: '" + match.Groups["level"].ToString() + "'");
}
```

Here's a method that implements the above:

**GetLevelRegex**:

```
private string GetLevelRegex(string userInput)
{
    string level = string.Empty;

    Match match = Regex.Match(userInput, "^.+level\\s+(?<level>\\d+).+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            Group group = match.Groups[i];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("group [" + i + "]:  Name: '" + group.Name + "' Value: " + group.Value);
        }

        level = match.Groups["level"].ToString();
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Level: '" +  level + "'");
    }

    return level;
}
```

**Option 2** (without Regex)

Declare a variable:

```
string level = string.Empty;
```

Ensure user input in not null or empty and contains the word "level":

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) && userInput.IndexOf("level", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{

}
```

Replace multiple spaces with single space

```
string tempInput = userInput.Replace(@"\s+", " ");
```

Get substring starting after the word "level"; remove space

```
level = userInput.Substring(userInput.IndexOf("level", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 5).TrimStart();
```

Which results in the following string: `100 and the cost is around 129.`

Now, the desired value is at the beginning of the string and ends when a space occurs. Get the desired value:

```
level = level.Substring(0, level.IndexOf(" "));
```

"level" now contains the following string: `100`

Here's a method that implements the above:

**GetLevel**:

```
private string GetLevel(string userInput)
{
    string level = string.Empty;

    //ensure user input isn't null or empty AND user input contains the word "level"
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) && userInput.IndexOf("level", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        //replace multiple spaces with single space
        string tempInput = userInput.Replace(@"\s+", " "); 

        //get substring starting after the word "level"; remove space
        level = userInput.Substring(userInput.IndexOf("level", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 5).TrimStart();

        //get text until a space is encountered
        level = level.Substring(0, level.IndexOf(" "));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("level: '" + level + "'");
    }

    return level;
}
```